# XCode. How Do I Run Two Versions on the Same Dev. Machine: Version 3.2.2 (Pre-release) & Version 3.2.1

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

Could someone walk me through the setup to run one version of XCode for iPad development - version 3.2.2 prerelease - and another version for iPhone/iPodTouch development - version 3.2.1

The reason I ask is because the pre-release version does not support building < 3.2 iPhone OS. Or if it does I haven't figured out the magic handshake to make that happen. If you know please pass it along. Cheers.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually change the install location when installing the beta versions... make it something like `/DeveloperBeta` instead of `/Developer`, then you can choose which version of the dev tools to run.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. That was easy ;-).

Comment: glad I could help... I ran across the same issue a few weeks ago and was shocked when I came to the answer.